# Is it valid/acceptable to define an instance method named 'new' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

When I do the following in irb I get this output:

```
>> class TestMe
>>   def new
>>     puts 'hi!'
>>   end
>> end
=> nil
>> TestMe.new.new
hi!
```

Additionally:

```
>> class TestMe
>> end
=> nil
>> TestMe.new.new
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for #<TestMe:0x00000101038750>
```

But when I'm writing some code in my text editor of choice that is calling an instance method named `new` (but is not the `Object` method `new` that instantiates new objects) it highlights `new` as if it were a reserved keyword:

```
@page = current_user.locations.new
```

Note that `locations` here returns a delegator class that does some heavy lifting (via this `new` method) and eventually does return a `Location.new` instance with some basic setup data ready to go, but `new` is not itself being called on a class object.  Is this an acceptable use of the method name or will I run into issues with it?

Comment: It's possible, but it'd sure lead to some discussion in a code review. In my mind, it's a bad idea to reuse "new" in Ruby, simply because it's such an ingrained method name. Ruby programmers have an expectation of what it means, and to look for the `initialize` method when needing to work on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first call to `.new` will invoke the constructor, and return an instance of your class. The second call to `.new` will invoke an instance method on that object. It's completely acceptable to define a `new` instance method.

In order to interfere with the constructor, you would have to define a *class-level* method called `new`. That method can invoke `super#new` (which invokes `Class#new`) to perform the actual creation of the object:

```
class Test
  def self.new
    puts "hi!"
    super
  end
end


x = Test.new # outputs "hi"
```

It's completely valid to overwrite `new` at both an instance and class level, so long as you define your custom `new` method to do something *sane*.

Comment: This is the power ruby gives one however this is not advisable except it is required

Comment: Great answer. (I've never dared do this in production code...)